# How can I get my playing card images to re-size on mobile like this example site? (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm attempting to use the same setup as found at this site: https://www.micski.dk/2023/01/18/how-to-show-playing-cards-in-wordpress/

When loading that page on a mobile device, the images appear to re-size automatically and do not wrap like they do on my site, which can be seen here: https://spectrefaxpoker.com/2023/05/01/session-1-33-95/

I'm sure I'm overlooking some simple CSS or something. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Tried multiple CSS edits but couldn't seem to get the images to stop wrapping on mobile.

Comment: have you fixed your issue? I can see it wraps. Also try to post snippets of what you have tried as well.

Comment: No. Haven't fixed it yet.